# How do I formally state that the highest random number chosen from a distribution is higher the more numbers I choose?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

How can I formally state that if I choose $p$ random numbers from a distribution with a certain mean and standard deviation and if I choose $r$ random numbers from the same distribution, the expected highest number chosen should be higher if I choose $p$ numbers than if I choose $r$ numbers, where $p \gt r$.

Comment: If $p>r$, then, for every $x$, $P(X_p\geqslant x)\geqslant P(X_r\geqslant x)$. This is called *stochastic domination* (of $X_r$ by $X_p$).

Comment: I appreciate that answer very much, but would you explain what the notation means?  Also, is there a way I can expect the highest number to be higher (not just greater than or equal to) if I choose p than if I choose r?

Comment: You can have a slightly stronger sense of stochastic domination, $P(X_p \ge x) > P(X_r \ge x)$; alternatively, if you're interested in expectation, you can have $E(X_p) > E(X_r)$.  Which of these you want probably depends on why exactly you want to make this statement.

Comment: Sorry but which part of "the notation" in my comment is unclear to you?

Comment: Forgive me for asking:  What do X subscript p and X subscript r stand for?

Comment: Highest numbers obtained from samples of the corresponding sizes. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: Thank you @ Did.  @ Michael Lugo, is there anything I have to show or any assumptions I have to make prior to making those statements or are they just understood to be true?  I would prefer the expectation statement.

Comment: Relatedly, if I want to formally show that if I choose p random numbers from a distribution with mean a and if I choose r random numbers from a distribution with mean b and the same SD (where p>r, a>b), that s/q > a/b, where s is the expected highest number from the p sample and q is the expected highest number from the r sample, E(Xp)/E(Xr) > a/b (correct?), is there anything I have to show or any assumptions I have to make?  @ Did, if you have an opinion it'd be welcome too.

Comment: @ Did, where did the answer go that was on this page this morning?  I was about to reply to it.

Comment: Anyway, the answer's author asked why this question was downvoted.  I don't know but wonder if it has something to do with the last comments I made, since there wasn't a reply?

Comment: @Michael Lugo , am I justified in the statement at 5/16, 13:14 ?  It seems like it's saying basically the same thing as yours at 5/15, 13:26:  With the same SD, the p distribution is expected to have a higher maximum jump from its mean than the r distribution does from its mean.

Comment: Please replace "distribution" with "sample."  p sample should have a higher maximum jump from its mean than the r sample does from its mean since the p sample has higher quantity.

Comment: @MichaelLugo would the latter form (with expectation) also be considered stochastic domination?